# Find documents where some field is equal to the object's _id

Tags: mongodb, find, objectid

Having documents with the following structure:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("5bf361ad61816223d7ab26b5"),
  other_field: ObjectId("5bf361ad61816223d7ab26b5")
}
{
  _id: ObjectId("5bf271ad61816223d7ab26b5"),
  other_field: ObjectId("5bf361ad61816223d7ab26b5")
}
```

How would I find documents where `_id` is equal to `other_field`.

I've tried `db.coll.find({ "$where": "this._id == this.other_field" })` without success (no documents are returned), while `db.coll.find({ "$where": "this.other_field" == this.other_field" })` correctly brings all documents in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I solved it:

```
db.coll.find({$where: function() { return this._id.str == this.other_field }})
```

Comment: If you are using mongodb **3.6** and above you can use `$expr`... Something like `db.groups.find({ $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$other_field "] }})`